# `useSelector` rerenders even when the object is the same

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am refactoring React app that was built using class syntax and `connect` to React hooks.

App is meant to be for debugging and one of the bugs that has to be fixed is that in the reducer file we are not returning the new state object so the component doesn't rerender.

```js
export default function comments(state = InitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_SORT": {
      state.sort = action.sort;
      return state;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This doesn't cause the app to rerender so the state doesn't update and that is fine. However, once I refactored the app to use React hooks and `useSelector` the component rerenders even with this code. Is there a way I could make it not rerender unless the new state object is returned?

This is how the store is setup:

```js
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      posts,
      sort,
    }),
    {},
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that **your reducer is mutating the existing state, and you can *never* mutate state in a Redux app**.

Both `useSelector` and `connect` will cause your component to re-render if you return new references. You'd need to show your `useSelector` for me to give a more specific answer as to what's going on.

Also, you *should* be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to write your Redux logic, including using the `createSlice` API to write your reducers.  It will drastically simplify your Redux code.

Comment: The problem of mutating state is done on purpose as this is debugging exercise. 



`const { sort } = useSelector((state) => state.sort);`

With the previous version (using class and connect) the app was buggy as state didn't change (which was expected as it was mutated in Redux).

However, now the app works without errors